# Table in word cut off the text at bottom of it?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I have problem with table cut off the text at the bottom of the table. I have tried all the solutions from checking warping, and other table properties, but nothing worked.

[image]

Comment: The question does not reflect a programming issue so you are probably better served by asking in a forum that especially targets the use of a software application. To reach a wider audience I'd suggest posting the question at http://www.superuser.com would be more helpful to you.

Comment: One replied to me, "It seems that you may have a superfluous Content Control in the footer of the document that is causing the table to be split across the page break."

Comment: That could be a possible reason, still asking at Superuser.com is probably your best option. In the meantime on the Developer tab you can activate Design Mode to see where the content controls have their boundaries.

Comment: @Avrahem Are you sure the problem row doesn't have an 'exact height'? That would be enough to cut off any content that extends below that height, even without the page break. Also, it is clear your document has some other content at the bottom of that page that could be obscuring the rest of that row.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the "Allow row to break across pages" would solve your issue but is probably obstructed by the splitted cells in column one. I'd merge the cells in column one to get equal number of cells in column one and uncheck the "Allow row to break across pages" options on the Table Properties Row Tab.

Comment: Nothing worked, from merging to allow row to break across pages... I tried most table properties

Answer (score 0):

Copy/paste the text to another part of the document outside of the table.
Then select the text and set Paragraph --> Indents/Spacing --> Line Spacing: Single
Copy/paste back to the table.